# Webdriver script using Java is not running when mcafee antivirus is turned on

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Web driver script using Java is not running when McAfee antivirus is turned on. Is there any way to run the web driver script without turning off the McAfee antivirus and run the script. This issue is in my client machine. They have McAfee antivirus installed in there systems. My client don't want to turn off the McAfee in their system and run the script.

Can anyone help me on this issue, how to run the web driver script without turning off the McAfee in my client machine?

Comment: Well *what* happens when it's turned on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebDriver is a wire protocol](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html), so you will need to add the Driver e.g. InternetExplorerDriver and port number (default is 5555) to Mcafee whitelist.